# Change Google account to Stack Exchange

Tags: support

Is it possible if I migrate my Google account with Stack Exchange to just a Stack Exchange account?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this is possible via the account recovery system but not very obvious. You can read the full instructions along with visual aids on Meta Stack Exchange:

[How do I change my OpenID provider(s)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/how-do-i-change-my-openid-providers/114704#114704)

If something goes wrong and you end up with two accounts, please [contact us](/contact) and we can merge them together for you.